Keyword name cannot be empty after post request with expected_status in robotframework
enter image description hereI'm going create Negative Test with post request by expected_status,but I confront Keyword name cannot be empty message.
InvalidPassword Test
    [Tags]    InvalidPassword
    Create Session    InvalidPassword     ${url_api}/${end_point_login}    
    Log To Console    ${url_api}/${end_point_login}
    ${body}=    Create Dictionary    mobile=*****     password=******        key=1
    ${header}=    Create Dictionary           Accept=application/Json
    ${response}=    POST On Session    InvalidPassword    ${url_api}/${end_point_login}    data=${body}    expected_status=422 

enter image description here

Hi @marysh, the complete warning/error message is not visible on the screenshot but I am assuming the error is related to the certificate. Try setting disable_warnings=1 with Create Session keyword. Here is the documentation. Hope this helps.

hi, Keyword name cannot be empty.

Yes but the error originated before that. Did you try setting disable_warnings=1 with Create Session keyword?

Check the generated html report files, the issue is way more easier to spot from there than from console output

See the report.html file that is generated by Robot Framework to track the issue, however, I have some tips for you from the code you have shared:

If you sent base_address/uri while creating session, send an empty uri while creating post request. If you sent base_address while creating session, send uri while creating post.

Example:
*** Variables ***
${base_address}     base_address of your API
${uri}              uri of your API
*** Test Cases ***
post_function
    Create Session    InvalidPassword     ${base_address}
    POST On Session   InvalidPassword     ${uri}    ...

OR
*** Variables ***
${the_whole_address}     base_address of your API/uri of your API
${uri}              
*** Test Cases ***
post_function
    Create Session    InvalidPassword     ${base_address}
    POST On Session   InvalidPassword     ${uri}    ...


Send the request's headers and use json instead of data while creating a post request

Example:
${response}=    POST On Session    InvalidPassword    ${uri}    json=${body}    headers=${header}    expected_status=422


Note that the tips work when you are using "Post on session" built-in function. If you use "Post Request" built-in function, the tips are different

